# Subquery inside "IN" Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT * FROM `image_appreciations`
WHERE `image_id` IN(SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `user_id` = '1')
```

Is my current query, it returns zero results

```
SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `user_id` = '1'
```

being the subquery returns around 8 id's which two of them are found in

```
SELECT * FROM `image_appreciations`
WHERE `image_id` IN(77,89)
```

And that works fine. But all together it fails. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your syntax looks correct to me... Here is a reference though just in case http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

Comment: check if `id IS NOT NULL` in your subquery

Comment: @rs.: Why would that make a difference?  If `id` is NULL, then that row will be ignored.

Comment: @Rocket It won't be ignored - it will "collapse" the whole IN expression to NULL.

Comment: Your query should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bb01/1

Comment: @rs.: I don't think that's true.  See the example I made: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67f7/2

Comment: @Rocket Dang! You are right! I managed to conflate NOT IN and IN. Going ashamed to the corner :(

Comment: @Rocket, you are correct and it was not me who replied to you previously :) , it will fail when you do `NOT IN`, example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d67f7/9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be done using `JOIN`. Below is an example using the implicit short-hand syntax.

```sql
SELECT * FROM image_appreciations a, images i
WHERE a.image_id = i.id AND i.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! Will accept when it allows me too :)

Comment: realize though that the join construct: FROM Table1, Table2 is not the standard used today

Comment: @Leslie what is the standard that is used today?

Comment: @Leslie: What do you by "the standard used today"?

Comment: sorry, using explicit JOIN statements in the query is today's standard.  INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN or just JOIN depending on the database.

Answer (score 4):

A subquery like this "should" work, odd that's it not.  Anyway, you can try using a `JOIN` to solve this.

```
SELECT * FROM `image_appreciations`
JOIN `images` ON `image_id` = `id`
WHERE `images`.`user_id` = '1'
```